# How do I get the average age or grade of my stored list

Tags: python

**I get an error in taking the values in the list what is the right code to input in getting the average in the list**

```
values = [["Name", 'Age', 'Grade']]

for i, val in enumerate(values):
 print(i, val)

while True:
   
  print("\n1 - Add\n2 - Show Report\n")
    
  choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
  
  if choice == 1:
   name = str(input("Input Name: "))
   age = int(input("Enter Age: "))
   grade = float(input("Enter Grade: "))
   values.append([name, age, grade])
   
   for i, val in enumerate(values):
    print(i, val)
  
  elif choice == 2:
   for i, val in enumerate(values):
    a = sum(val[1] / i)
    print("The average age in the list is", a)
    b = sum(val[2] / i)
    print("The average grade in the list is", b)
```

This should be the output of the program

Should I add a code to remove 'Age' and get the Sum then divide? 
**Sample output**

```
0 ['Name', 'Age', 'Grade']

1 - Add
2 - Show

Enter your choice: 1
Input name: Bob
Input Age: 24
Input Grade: 90
0 ['Name', 'Age', 'Grade']
1 ['Bob', 24, 90.0]

1 - Add
2 - Show

Enter your choice: 1
Input name: Jun
Input Age: 20
Input Grade: 95
0 ['Name', 'Age', 'Grade']
1 ['Bob', 24, 90.0]
2 ['Jun', 20, 95.0]

1 - Add
2 - Show

Enter your choice: 2
The average age in the list is 22
The average grade in the list is 92.5
```

Comment: Why don't you use dictionary instead of list?

Answer (score 0):

**Without changing too much of your code :**

Here is your list of list (which is basically a table)

```
Name, Age, Grade
Bob, 24, 90.0
Jun, 20, 95.0
```

Remember that the first row are headers (strings) that cannot be divided. You have to ignore it. Plus the index of that row is 0 and a division by 0 breaks the universe. Change that to enumerate(values[1:]) to skip the first row.

```
 elif choice == 2:
   for i, val in enumerate(values):
    a = sum(val[1] / i)
    print("The average age in the list is", a)
    b = sum(val[2] / i)
    print("The average grade in the list is", b)
```

Then you have to sum all grades and all ages. One way to do it is to put it to a variable. There for each row (student) it will add his age to the sum of ages and same for his grade. Then we can calculate the average by dividing these values with the number of student present in the list. Size of the list -1 because we removed the first row. len(values) gives the number of element in that list.

```
 elif choice == 2:
     # EDIT: i forgot to set these var before calling +=, it would cause a NameError (undefined).
     sumAge = sumGrade = 0
     for i, val in enumerate(values[1:]):
        sumAge += val[1]
        sumGrade += val[2]
     averageAge = sumAge / (len(values)-1)         
     averageGrade = sumGrade / (len(values)-1)
     print("The average age in the list is", averageAge)
     print("The average grade in the list is", averageGrade)
```

**Doing more**

In fact I would use object, because your list is just a list of student described by their name, age and grade.

```
class Student:
    """A class representing a student, described with a Name, Age and Grade"""
    def __init__(self, name :str, age :int, grade :float):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.grade = grade
```

So you can set your list of students almost the same way as before

```
students: List[Student] = []

# There you can set your input. 
studentA = Student("Bob", 24, 95.0)
students.append(studentA)
studentB = Student("Jun", 20, 90.0)
students.append(studentB)
```

If you're wondering how class works. Here is a example of a part of your code translate to a Class. :

```
from typing import List

class Student:
    """A class representing a student, described with a Name, Age and Grade"""
    # __init__ is called when you create an object of type Student
    def __init__(self, name :str, age :int, grade :float):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.grade = grade
    
    # __str__ is  called in print(instanceofstudent), we can choose what to print, so we don't have to think about it when calling print(student)
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"__str__ : {self.name} - {self.age} - {self.grade}"

    # __repr__ is called in print(listofstudent), same here, we choose what to display when we print a list of students.
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"__repr__ : {self.name} - {self.age} - {self.grade}"

students: List[Student] = [] # :List[Student] is just to give python more information about what we will put in the list. 

# There you can set your input. 
studentA = Student("Bob", 24, 95.0) # here we call __init__
students.append(studentA)
studentB = Student("Jun", 20, 90.0) # here we call __init__
students.append(studentB)

print(students) # here we call student.__repr__ to print all element of the list

sumAge = sumGrade = 0
for student in students:
    print(student) # here we call student.__str__
    print(student.name) # here we get the attributes directly

    sumAge += student.age
    sumGrade += student.grade

print(f"SumAge : {sumAge}")
print(f"SumAge : {sumGrade}")

averageAge = sumAge/len(students)
averageGrade = sumGrade/len(students)

print(f"average age of students : {averageAge}")
print(f"average grade of students : {averageGrade}")
```